# what methods ca you call on JAvascript err in catch statement

Tags: javascript, methods, try-catch

i have 
try{
..code..
}catch(err){
err.### what methods do i have access to here ###
}

or a location where they are all defined please, as ive search all over and cannot find a definition of what exists.

I have come across 
.description (which mostly is 'undefined')
.stack (i think not sure if this works)

Comment: maybe it will help if i give more detail, 
I have rhino being used under a java library, and have the err defined within some Javascript I am running, so i dont need to worry about the cross platform.
but i want to print out all the error details, more useful would be the line number and class or method where the error originated.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can view a full list of properties on the `Error` object at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/error), your big cross-browser one is `.message`, though if it's a [more specific error type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/error#Error_types), there will be additional properties.

Comment: Here's the API for IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dww52sbt(v=vs.94).aspx. You will notice that only `.message` is shared like Nick mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

an example below:-

```
try
{
 undefinedfunction()
}
catch(err)
{
 alert('An error has occurred: '+err.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're new with JS:
In Firefox (You should have all browsers to begin with for testing)
install the addon Firebug.

Then just call console.log(err) and reload page with Firebug console open.

Click the log and you'll find all the data on the object you could ever need. :)